# Not able to load JSON Data in Android

Tags: android, json

I am new in JSON Parsing and need some help in retrieving data from  a JSON URL...
I have read many tutorials on JSON Parsing and they all helped me a lot but not I am stuck..
I am trying to retrieve data from a

```
URL = "http://mygogolfteetime.com/iphone/topfive/155"
```

but my `Json object` returns **null** value in the log.

However I can retrieve the same data from another

```
URL = "http://api.mygogolfteetime.com/top_5.php?id=155&apikey=eart3562@#bety7*&6b12zAf*&etrqvbn*&LMQW"
```

I am also attaching my code so that one can help me in solving my problem..

Code for My Test Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

private static final String url = "http://mygogolfteetime.com/iphone/topfive/155";
private static final String TAG = "Top5";


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.v(TAG, "URL: "+String.valueOf(url));
    JsonParser jParse = new JsonParser();
    JSONObject json = jParse.getJSONfromUrl(url);
    Log.v(TAG, "Json: "+String.valueOf(json));
    }
}
```

This is the code of my JsonParser Activity:

```
public class JsonParser {

    static InputStream is;
    static JSONObject jObj;
    static String json = null;
    private static final String TAG = "Top5";

    public JSONObject getJSONfromUrl(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

I have also added the permission for the Internet in the Manifest file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Thanks in advance...

sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Why are you using HttpPost. Isn't it supposed to be HttpGet?

Comment: @ChitranshuAsthana HttpPost sends a request, server replies with a json string.

Comment: the first link probably doesn't send a reply, or an expected reply , your code looks fine.

Comment: Yup, culprit here is http request method. I just checked and http://mygogolfteetime.com/iphone/topfive/155 does not allow HTTP-POST method. You will have to use HTTP-GET to get the response. Once you have the response, rest of the code looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user following function to get json response either JSONArray/JSONObject

```
public Object request(String url) {


            try {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    String strRes = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    Object resObj = strRes.startsWith("[") ? new JSONArray(
                            strRes) : new JSONObject(strRes);
                    return resObj;
                }

                return response;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

    }
```

Comment: The above code is also returning null value when I modify my code.. Still need some other solution..

Thanks anyways..

Comment: I got NetworkOnMainThreadException (From API Level 11) because I am using Android 4.1. So create AsyncTask and do your paring in doInBackground(). This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please chk this...

```
public class Top5  extends Activity {


    private static final String TAG = "Top5";


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //    Log.v(TAG, "URL: "+String.valueOf(url));
        //    JsonParser jParse = new JsonParser();
        //    JSONObject json = jParse.getJSONfromUrl(url);
        //    Log.v(TAG, "Json: "+String.valueOf(json));

        try {

            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
//          URL url = new URL(url .toString());
            URL url = new URL("http://mygogolfteetime.com/iphone/topfive/155");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setUseCaches(false); 
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.connect();
            System.out.println("Connection :"+connection.getResponseCode());

            String rawObjects = readZipStream(connection.getInputStream());

            Log.i("ROW OBJECT::::::::::::","************"+rawObjects);
        } catch (Exception exception) {

            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static String readZipStream(InputStream is) throws IOException,
    ParseException {

        StringBuilder rawObjects = new StringBuilder();

        InputStream zis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis));
        try {

            String readedLine;
            while ((readedLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("readedLine :"+readedLine);
                if (readedLine != null && readedLine.trim().length() > 0) {
                    rawObjects.append(readedLine);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            close(br);
            close(zis);
        }
        return rawObjects.toString();

    }
    private static void close(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }
    }



    private static void close(Reader reader) {
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }
    }
}
```

Result is comming like this::

```
08-17 11:07:20.828: INFO/System.out(455): readedLine :{"top5":[{"course_id":"127","member_id":"155","created_date":"1345098492","status":"1","golfcourse_name":"SilverHorn Golf Club","facilities":"","holes":"0"},{"course_id":"93","member_id":"155","created_date":"1345098472","status":"1","golfcourse_name":"sonu","facilities":"4","holes":"0"},{"course_id":"89","member_id":"155","created_date":"1344838832","status":"1","golfcourse_name":"ranjeet golf course","facilities":"4","holes":"9"}]}
```